# Generate a new VeraCrypt container on the linux command line

Tags: linux, veracrypt

I am looking for an example how to create a new non-hidden ext4 VeraCrypt container on the linux command line with as little user interaction as possible. The other parameters (e.g. encryption) should be the current default choices of the GUI.

`veracrypt -h` gives a comprehensive list of options. In particular it says:

```
--create[=VOLUME_PATH]
 Create a new volume. Most options are requested from the user if not specified
 on command line. See also options --encryption, -k, --filesystem, 
--hash, -p, --random-source, --quick, --size, --volume-type. Note that passing some of the
 options may affect security of the volume (see option -p for more information).
```

so it provides a list of options to consider. An example would be way more helpful, since I would need to look through all these options' descriptions in order to see how the arguments need to be formated.

Comment: Isn't the man page or website/faqs more helpful?

Comment: The man pages provide the same info as `veracrypt -h`. The webpages refer to `veracrypt -h`. I am myself surprised that I couldn't find this. Perhaps the task of generating crypt containers frequently is not so common. For me it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example command line to generate a VeryCrypt container on Linux is

```
veracrypt -t --create test.vc --password test --hash sha512 --encryption AES --filesystem ext4 --volume-type normal -k "" --pim 0 --size 10M.
```

Adjust the parameters to your needs. Some of them are actually defaults, here.

Pre-pending the switch -t to the list of arguments helps.

Answer (score 1):

See the
[VeraCrypt Command Line Usage page](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Command%20Line%20Usage.html),
where at the end are listed all the sub-options that are specific to `/create`.

An example is also listed :

> Create a 10 MB file container using the password test and formatted using FAT:

```
"C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\VeraCrypt Format.exe" /create c:\Data\test.hc /password test /hash sha512 /encryption serpent /filesystem FAT /size 10M /force
```

Comment: Ok, that should translate to `veracrypt --create test.vc --password test --hash sha512 --encryption serpent --filesystem FAT --size 10M --force` on linux. That command does not throw an error, but it does not seem to do anything either (I tried a few variations too). One relevant question may be how it collects the random data for which it usually asks for user input.

Comment: You might raise such questions on the [VeraCrypt Forums](https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/).

Comment: I seen now an error message displayed in a box (it was hidden before for some reason). It says "This feature is currently supported only in text mode.", whatever that means.

Comment: Ok, found the answer for the last problem here: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/TrueCrypt/Problembehebung/ . Prepending the switch `-t` to the list of arguments helps. I now have `veracrypt -t --create test.vc --password test --hash sha512 --encryption AES --filesystem ext4 --volume-type normal -k "" --pim 0 --size 10M`. I am only hoping that `--pim 0` does what it should (choose the default values). I didn't find documentation for that parameter.